# What graph structure is being assumed in specific recursive DFS R example?

Tags: r, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

I am tring to figure out the data structure that is being assumed for
the recursive DFS R code snippet shown in
https://www.algorithms-and-technologies.com/dfs/r. I initially assumed
that it was an Adjacency list, something like:

```
start <- list(
  "0" = c("1","2"),
  "1" = c("3","4"),
  "2" = c("5","6"),
  "3" = c(),
  "4" = c(),
  "5" = c(),
  "6" = c()
)
```

but I couldn't get that to work. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as though they are assuming something like this:

```r
thelist <- list(value = 123,
                children = list(list(value = 456,
                                     children = list()),
                                list(value = 789,
                                     children = list())))
```

i.e. each node is a list with a `value` (which will be matched to `target` when searched), and a list of children which are nodes in the same format.

EDITED TO ADD:

This code converts your `start` to something in the format of `thelist`:

```r
start <- list(
  "0" = c("1","2"),
  "1" = c("3","4"),
  "2" = c("5","6"),
  "3" = c(),
  "4" = c(),
  "5" = c(),
  "6" = c()
)

toNode <- function(n) {
  result <- list(value = n)
  children <- list()
  names <- start[[n]]
  for (i in seq_along(names)) {
    cat("Processing node ", n, " child ", names[i], "\n")
    children[[i]] <- toNode(names[i])
  }
  result$children <- children
  result
}

thelist <- toNode("0")
#> Processing node  0  child  1 
#> Processing node  1  child  3 
#> Processing node  1  child  4 
#> Processing node  0  child  2 
#> Processing node  2  child  5 
#> Processing node  2  child  6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can print the final value of `thelist`, but it's pretty ugly.  Here's a reformatted version of what `dput(thelist)` gives:

```
list(value = "0", children = list(
  list(value = "1", children = list(
    list(value = "3", children = list()),
    list(value = "4", children = list())
  )),
  list(value = "2", children = list(
    list(value = "5", children = list()),
    list(value = "6", children = list())
  ))
))
```

Comment: To add to the answer, `for(i in seq_along(start$children))` shows that the tree doesn't need to be binary, `seq_along` will create sequences depending on how many children each node has.

Comment: So thelist explicitly lists grand-children (i.e. children of children)?  Just to make sure I understand what you are saying, would you mind taking the ordinary adjacency list called start that I show in my original post and translate it into what you have in mind?  start is an adjacency list for a graph that they show on their web page.  Sorry to be a pain!

Comment: I've done that now.

Comment: Oh, I think I finally see how this works.  The theList structure explicitly lays out an entire DFS search starting from node 0, and this is what your toNode function is outputting, do I have that right?  Thanks very much for the explanation!

Thanks also for the dput reference.  I had not been aware of that function.